# Speed up Mission Control Preview Animation

Tags: macos, mission-control

Once in Mission Control, I like to able to preview the contents of each the Desktops in the larger preview section instead of only relying on the thumbnail view.  You can accomplish this by entering Mission control and then hitting<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+left/right arrow.

However, the animation for switching between desktops in the main preview screen is so slow that it because unbearably useless for as fast as I like to work.  Is there a way to actually speed that animation up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing with the <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, on its own it does nothing for me, if I click a space it exits Mission Control to that space, slowly. Shift generally slows down OSX animations (for example hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and minimize a window). I use <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> + left or right arrows to move back and forth between previews. Well, mostly I use a three fingered swipe. Both of those are fast.

You can enable the <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> + arrow shortcuts in **Keyboard Preferences** under the **MissionControl** section of the  **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab.

Comment: I edited my question to indicate that I really meant ctrl+shift+arrow keys.  For whatever ctrl+left/right without holding shift doesn't work in Mission Control for me.

Comment: Odd, I don't think I enabled them specifically, but check your keyboard preferences' shortcuts tab and check to make sure that they are enabled for MissionControl. I updated the answer with that info.

Comment: My problem here was that in my Keyboard Preferences for Mission Control I actually had my keyboard shortcut for "Move right a space" and "Move left a space" bound to cntrl+shift+arrow.  This is why I had to hold shift to go left/right when in the Mission Control preview mode... and holding shift forced slow mission.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using ctrl-shift to do this. This exits Mission Control, but selects the desktop you clicked on. The reason the animation is so slow is that you're held shift (which slows down many OS X animations). Holding ctrl does nothing.

I think what you want to do is switch the preview area of Mission Control to show the contents of another desktop.
**This is accomplished by <kbd>option</kbd> clicking on the Desktop you want to preview.**

Comment: You can see this effect across much of the UI - holding shift and performing other things like docking and undocking apps and windows. Finder also has the super slow mode whilst shift is depressed.

Comment: Using option and clicking is OK.  I'd prefer keyboard shortcuts, but I'll accept this unless I can figure out why Cntrl+left/right arrow aren't working for me.