# Lion: Switching Spaces with Key Controls darn slow?

Tags: macos, mac, spaces, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speed up Mission Control Preview Animation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23222/speed-up-mission-control-preview-animation)

I loved to use Spaces in Snow Leopard. Now with Mission Control I love using the feature even more. However as many people on the web pointed out, the animation when switching between to spaces is really slow.

And yeah I know that it's faster when using the Magic Mouse, a Trackpad or anything else. It's also faster for me. However I like switching between Spaces with ALT-ArrowKeys like I used to.

Numerous people already pointed out the same problem: See [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1198918) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/313572/os-x-lion-desktop-switching-speed)

Everybody says the same. It's fast enough when you use the Trackpad or Magic Mouse or even some CMD-key with the Space-Number, but it's really slow when you try switching between s

Comment: It would be better to offer a bounty or somehow improve the other questions rather than asking the same thing. It's clear some macs would be faster with better resources / GPU but asking again seems less clear to be of benefit to the site.